# mysql count function

Tags: mysql, count

I'm interested in how I can write mysql query if I want to count some column from table (mysql database) where that column must be chosen within another query ?
like this 
`SELECT COUNT(OTHER_QUERY) FROM TABLE`

I have column named port and want to count this column within another query like this (select port where port='GCP';

I'm trying to do this task but with no result (despite of helping)
I'm writing like so => 
`SELECT COUNT(port) from data WHERE port = (select port from data where port='GCP')`
So I want to count column port which are equal to GCP

please help with this task :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the original query in a sub-select:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.column)
FROM (other_query) A
```

For your second query, I believe this should get what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.column)
FROM (other_query) A
WHERE A.port='GCP'
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be like below :

```
Select (select count(colum_nname) from table2 )  as totalvalues from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this :

Want total number of ports if it's value is GCP.

If so, then this is the syntax:

SELECT COUNT(port) AS alias WHERE port = GCP;

You may find this [MySQL COUNT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-function.php) resources useful.